# Number of resources seized based on individual agent parameter

Tags: java, resources, anylogic, pool, agent-based-modeling

There are two types of agents - large and small. So, I introduced parameter parIsLarge, which is boolean (true is large, false is small). Large agent requires a combination of two units of resources - resourceA and resourceB. Small agent requires one unit of resource - either resourceA or resourceB.

First, I wanted to use a function but it failed to work. I replaced the function by code in seize block but it still doesn't work. [The code to assign the right resources based on agent's parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1yTS.png). [This is the error encountered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uid4g.png). Please help to correct the code

Comment: you have to use a function, you can't use if/else in there

Answer (score 1):

The Seize block code only allows 1 line of code, not several. Hence, you need to move your code into a separate function, say 'f_GetResourcePools`.

It should take 1 input argument `agent` of the type flowing through the seize block. And it should return a `ResourcePool[][]`.

In the seize block, you simply call that function now using `f_getResourcePools(agent)`. (not even a `;` is needed!)

PS: Start learning about the difference between code boxes that allow as many code lines as you like and those that only allow 1 line. The latter is used where block characteristics are "asking" a question (in this case "which resource pools should be used?").

Answer (score 0):

Using a separate function is neater, but the code you wrote can be written on a single line by using a ternary operator.

`agent.parIsLarge ? new ResourcePool[][]{{resResourceA, resResourceB}} : new ResourcePool[][]{{resResourceA},{resResourceB}}`